# animate part of the way along Follow Path

Tags: animation, constraints, path

I want to have an object Follow a Path until some percent of the path and then stop Follow Path:

[image]

I can set the frames to animate the path:

[image]

and the offset time to start the animation:

[image]

But I don't see a way to stop the animation (small cube towards large cube) when it is part-way along the path.  I created and aligned the objects and path with the empty objects (in blue), so that they would all be aligned.  And actually it would be better if I could stop the animation at some intermediate path vertex.

In 3ds Max, I am able to frame-key % path, so that I can speed up and slow down a path-based animation.

How can I accomplish this?   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your follow path constraint like this:

[image]

Then keyframe offset from 0 to 0.8

[image]

Result:

https://youtu.be/6IdUgpwBVgw

Comment: It appears then that I do not have to use the "Animate path" button, correct?